# How to compare values with more or less

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement, statistics

I have a dataframe and i want to compare variables in line 3 using  if statement with the use of more or less

let's say i want to compare the same values in third column with more or less 0.2

```
data >
NAME         A      B      C      D
first        3      2      4      5
second       1      2      3      4
third        7      7.1    7.5    6.9
four         2      1      0      5
```

here  a program to compare the exact values

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  d <- i+1
  for (j in d:4) {
    if(data [3,i] == data [3,j] ){
        print(paste("The columns" , colnames(data[,i]) ,"and " , colnames(data[,i]) , "are equal"))
    }
  }
}
```

Here it retuns nothings because the program compares the exacte values and me i want to compare that have the same values more or less 0.2

the result i want is

```
the column A and B are equal  
the column A and D are equal
```

it's because A(=7) + or - the same as B(7.1)
and the same thing for D
A(=7) + or - D (6.9)

Thank you

Comment: What is the expected output for your data?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i want to compare the third row, as you can see A=7 so it's equal to B (+ ou - 0.2) and it's the same for D   so the result i want is , the column A and B are equal  the column A and D are equal, i edited the question please see what i added, thank you

Comment: A solution to problems like this often use, 1) Subtract one from the other, 2) Check if the `abs()` value is less than (`<`) the range you're looking for, e.g. 0.2.  e.g. something like, `abs(data [3,i] - data [3,j]) < 0.2`

Answer (score 0):

Take the combination of columns then compare with tolerance:

```
df1 <- read.table(text ="
NAME         A      B      C      D
first        3      2      4      5
second       1      2      3      4
third        7      7.1    7.5    6.9
four         2      1      0      5", header = TRUE)


tolerance = 0.2

cbind(df1, 
      combn(colnames(df1[, 2:5]), 2, FUN = function(x){
        paste0(x[ 1 ],
               ifelse(abs(df1[, x[ 1 ] ] - df1[, x[ 2 ] ]) <= tolerance, "=", "!="),
               x[ 2 ])
      }))


#     NAME A   B   C   D    1    2    3    4    5    6
# 1  first 3 2.0 4.0 5.0 A!=B A!=C A!=D B!=C B!=D C!=D
# 2 second 1 2.0 3.0 4.0 A!=B A!=C A!=D B!=C B!=D C!=D
# 3  third 7 7.1 7.5 6.9  A=B A!=C  A=D B!=C  B=D C!=D
# 4   four 2 1.0 0.0 5.0 A!=B A!=C A!=D B!=C B!=D C!=D
```